# How to use Generic typeclass for enum type to make toStr/fromStr?

Tags: purescript

I can not wrap my head around how to make use of `Generic` typeclass for a simple case:

I have an enum (nullary sum) type and I want to get two functions for converting to/from String, without boilerplate.

```
data Some = First | Second


derive instance Generic Some _

toStr :: Some -> String
toStr = 
  ...

fromStr :: String -> Maybe Some
fromStr =
  ...
```

How this should be implemented?

Comment: If you have a specific type you don't need a generic implementation to work with it.

This is a subset of "GenericShow" + some simple generic parsing which can handle only sum types without "arguments": https://try.purescript.org/?gist=22f4136a0286f78bbe807f5be11ab1f5

I can turn this into a proper response if you like it ;-)

Comment: But maybe you thought about just using `genericShow`? You can use it directly against any type which has `Generic` instance - `log $ Data.Show.genericShow First` should work out of the box. I'm not sure though if there is any solution for parsing enums - we could possibly package something up :-)

Comment: Ok, thanks, so there still a need be for some "boilerplate" (for fromStrs thing), or something wrapped in a library.

Comment: @paluh you can put it as a response to mark this thing closed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is an answer:
try.purescript.org/?gist=22f4136a0286f78bbe807f5be11ab1f5